# How to get a unique combination of two columns?

Tags: mysql

I have table like below

```
member  follower
A         B
B         C
C         D
E         A
B         A
B         E
D         E
```

In this above data A - B, B - A having same relationship.. i need unique row either A - B OR B - A

Output should be like below

```
member  follower
A         B
B         C
C         D
E         A
B         E
D         E
```

I have solved but i just wanted to know whether my logic proper or not.

Comment: Then add your query.

Comment: show your query here to see your logic for evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all the query you need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(member,follower) member_1
             , GREATEST(member,follower) member_2 
          FROM my_table;
```

The rest is noise.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is this :

```
 SELECT greatest(t.member,t.follower) as member1,
        least(t.member,t.follower) as member2
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY 
       greatest(t.member,t.follower) ,
       least(t.member,t.follower)
```

Comment: The group by is for distinct values, with no group by - there will be duplicates(I can also use distinct, but what does it matter?) @Strawberry . Though I agree about deleting the first one .

Comment: This forum is littered with literally thousands of posts incorrectly using GROUP BY clauses. It starts with seemingly inocuous statements like the one provided above, and ends in illiterate carnage. So, 'what does it matter?' You tell me.

Comment: You have a good point, nevertheless , group by works just fine here, its a simple question , and there is nothing wrong with this solution. I never declared that this is the best solution. It's just a force of habit. @Strawberry

Comment: You deserved one more than I did.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT member, follower
FROM yourtable
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE CONCAT(member, follower) = REVERSE(CONCAT(member, follower))) <= 1
```